# Integration of a particular waveform

Tags: integration

Starting from this equation $$I=\alpha\dot{u}-C_0\dot{V}$$
knowing that $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}Idt=\frac{V_{cc}}{R}\frac{T}{2}$$
where $t_1, t_2, V_{cc},V$ are as in figure ($t_1=0, t_2=\frac{T}{2}$) 
how can one obtain the following result?
$$V_{cc}=\frac{R\alpha}{RC_0\omega+\frac{\pi}{2}}\omega u_m$$ where $u_m$ is the oscillation amplitude of $u$? I tried to move into the frequency domain, but I do not get pi/2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZwtj.jpg)

Comment: Where does $\omega$ and $u_m$ come from? I get $V_{cc}=\frac{2R\alpha}{T}(u(T/2)-u(0))-\frac{2R C_0}{T}(V(T/2)-V(0))$.

Comment: I think it comes from a switch to the frequency domain, writing the time derivatives as a multiplication by $j\omega$

Answer (score 0):

$I = \alpha \frac{du}{dt} - C_0 \frac{dV}{dt}$

$Idt = \alpha du - C_0dV$

Integrating on both sides

$\int_{0}^{\frac{T}{2}} Idt = \int_{-u_m}^{u_m} \alpha du - \int_{-V_{cc}}^{V_{cc}}C_0 dV$

$\frac{V_{cc}T}{2R} = 2\alpha u_m - 2C_0V_{cc}$

Collecting $V_{cc}$

$V_{cc}\left[2C_0 + \frac{T}{2R}\right] = 2\alpha u_m$

$T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

$V_{cc}\left[2C_0 + \frac{2\pi}{2R\omega}\right] = 2\alpha u_m$

$2V_{cc}\left[\dfrac{C_0R\omega + \frac{\pi}{2}}{R\omega}\right] = 2\alpha u_m$

$V_{cc} = \dfrac{R\alpha}{C_0R\omega + \frac{\pi}{2}} \omega u_m$

Goodluck